# Is it possible to perfectly fit a large image inside a smaller div?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm wondering, is it possible to accomplish this? I'm going crazy :/

Let's say I've a 1200x628 image, and I want it to be displayed inside a div with a fixed height 880x200.

Every solution I tried the image is always somehow cropped to fit the div, so I'm asking, is it possible to auto-resize the image in order to have it ALL (and I mean all :P) displayed inside the div with its aspect ratio? Like zoomed out, I don't really know how to explain this lol hoping you get the point.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please post your solutions (_Every solution I tried_)

Comment: The height is fixed and the width is also fixed. if yes then there will always be a liitle bit of cropping. if no you can use the object fit method. there are enough examples (and answers how you can use that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can used `object-fit` css property, like below example:

```css
.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 880px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/29/17/26/photographer-5353515_1280.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the aspect ratio:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

but the problem with this solution is that the image will not take the full area of it's parent!

to make it fill the full area you have to break the aspect ratio:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

`<img src="xxx.jpg" width='880' />`

`880` is the width of your div or the image width you want to show

Make sure you *don't* give any height attribute.

Example

```html
Actual width of image is 1200px, what you see below is of width 100
<br />

<img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Pkmq1nm3skO0-j693JTMd7RL0Zk=/0x0:2012x1341/1200x800/filters:focal(0x0:2012x1341)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/47070706/google2.0.0.jpg" width='100' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You give the outer div its dimensions and then set the images css with width:100%; and height:100%;

Other option would be to set the image as a background-image and use background-size: cover;